# Why does using a constructor for writing to an array cause a buffer overflow but a similar class function does not?

Tags: c++

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. I'm getting a warning stating that there is a buffer overrun issue when using the commented out code here:

```
if (arrayNum < sizeof(classRosterArray) / sizeof(classRosterArray[0])) {
        //classRosterArray[arrayNum++] = new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age, daysToCompleteCourses, degreeProgram);
        classRosterArray[arrayNum++]->addStudentData(studentID, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age, daysToCompleteCourses, degreeProgram);
    }
```

But not the function call. It says there the writeable size is 40 bytes but that 48 bytes might be written. The classRosterArray is an array of Student obj pointers (something that is required in the project).

Here's the code:

```
//for stackoverflow
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const string studentData[] = {
        "A1,John,Smith,John1989@gm ail.com,20,30,35,40,SECURITY",
        "A2,Suzan,Erickson,Erickson_1990@gmailcom,19,50,30,40,NETWORK",
        "A3,Jack,Napoli,The_lawyer99yahoo.com,19,20,40,33,SOFTWARE",
        "A4,Erin,Black,Erin.black@comcast.net,22,50,58,40,SECURITY",
        "A5,John,Snow,kingofthenorth@winterfell.gov,33,20,21,22,SOFTWARE"
};
size_t sd_elementNum = sizeof(studentData) / sizeof(studentData[0]);
string sd_temp;
enum DegreeProgram { SECURITY, NETWORK, SOFTWARE };

class Student {
public:
    static const int COURSE_NUM = 3;
    Student();
    Student(
        string newStudentID,
        string newFirstName,
        string newLastName,
        string newEmailAddress,
        int newAge,
        int newDaysToCompleteCourses[],
        DegreeProgram newDegreeProgram
    );
    void addStudentData(
        string newStudentID,
        string newFirstName,
        string newLastName,
        string newEmailAddress,
        int newAge,
        int newDaysToCompleteCourses[],
        DegreeProgram newDegreeProgram
    );
//private: these are normally private but I'm saving a few lines that would normally be accessors
    string studentID;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string emailAddress;
    int age;
    int daysToCompleteCourses[COURSE_NUM]{};
    DegreeProgram degreeProgram;
};
class Roster {
public:
    Student* classRosterArray[5] = { new Student, new Student, new Student, new Student, new Student };
    void add(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, int daysInCourse1, int daysInCourse2, int daysInCourse3, DegreeProgram degree);
    ~Roster();
private:
    unsigned int arrayNum = 0;
};
Student::Student() {
    studentID = "";
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    emailAddress = "";
    age = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < COURSE_NUM; ++i)
        daysToCompleteCourses[i] = 0;
    DegreeProgram degreeProgram = SECURITY;
    return;
};
Student::Student(string newStudentID, string newFirstName, string newLastName, string newEmailAddress, int newAge, int newDaysToCompleteCourses[], DegreeProgram newDegreeProgram) {
    studentID = newStudentID;
    firstName = newFirstName;
    lastName = newLastName;
    emailAddress = newEmailAddress;
    age = newAge;
    for (int i = 0; i < COURSE_NUM; ++i)
        daysToCompleteCourses[i] = newDaysToCompleteCourses[i];
    degreeProgram = newDegreeProgram;
    return;
}
void Student::addStudentData(string newStudentID, string newFirstName, string newLastName, string newEmailAddress, int newAge, int newDaysToCompleteCourses[], DegreeProgram newDegreeProgram) {
    studentID = newStudentID;
    firstName = newFirstName;
    lastName = newLastName;
    emailAddress = newEmailAddress;
    age = newAge;
    for (int i = 0; i < COURSE_NUM; ++i)
        daysToCompleteCourses[i] = newDaysToCompleteCourses[i];
    degreeProgram = newDegreeProgram;
    return;
}
void Roster::add(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, int daysInCourse1, int daysInCourse2, int daysInCourse3, DegreeProgram degreeProgram) {
    int daysToCompleteCourses[Student::COURSE_NUM] = { daysInCourse1, daysInCourse2, daysInCourse3 };
    if (arrayNum < sizeof(classRosterArray) / sizeof(classRosterArray[0])) {
        classRosterArray[arrayNum++] = new Student(studentID, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age, daysToCompleteCourses, degreeProgram);
        //classRosterArray[arrayNum++]->addStudentData(studentID, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age, daysToCompleteCourses, degreeProgram);
    }
    else {
        cout << "The class roster is full. No students can be added at this time. Please see your system administrator." << endl;
    }
}
void processStudentData(Roster& classRoster, const string studentData[], size_t sd_elementNum) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sd_elementNum; ++i) {
        string sd_temp, sd_array[9];
        DegreeProgram degreeProgram;

        //begin parsing the element's string
        istringstream sd_stringstream(studentData[i]);
        int j = 0;
        while (getline(sd_stringstream, sd_temp, ',')) {
            sd_array[j] = sd_temp;
            j += 1;
        }
        if (sd_array[8] == "SECURITY") {
            degreeProgram = SECURITY;
        }
        else if (sd_array[8] == "SOFTWARE") {
            degreeProgram = SOFTWARE;
        }
        else if (sd_array[8] == "NETWORK") {
            degreeProgram = NETWORK;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error: " << sd_array[0] << " does not have a valid degreeProgram setup. Please address this before proceeding.";
        }
        classRoster.add(sd_array[0], sd_array[1], sd_array[2], sd_array[3], stoi(sd_array[4]), stoi(sd_array[5]), stoi(sd_array[6]), stoi(sd_array[7]), degreeProgram);
    };
    return;
}

void main() {
    Roster classRoster;

    //Main Functionality
    processStudentData(classRoster, studentData, sd_elementNum);
    //this is where I'd use a print function
    classRoster.~Roster();


    //return;
    system("pause>0");
};
```

Note: The project dictates that I have to use arrays, not vectors.
What is the function call doing that the constructor is not? And how can I tighten up the constructor to address this warning? Or do I have the completely wrong idea?

Comment: Do you need arrays of pointers? Please give a [mcve]. Seems you are leaking memory. Coming from Java/C#? You know C++ has no garbage collector, right?

Comment: What tool are you using that's giving you the warning?

Comment: If you are passing `classRosterArray` to another function to invoke the `addStudentData` function, then sizeof() will not return the full array size, only the size of the pointer.

Comment: What would be better is if you showed your entire code to `Student`.  Better yet, give us a [mcve]

Comment: `sizeof(classRosterArray) / sizeof(classRosterArray[0])` is definitely suspect. Need to see it in context.

Comment: *The project dictates that I have to use arrays, not vectors.* -- Were you also told to use  this: `void main()` when it should be `int main()`?  Also, what is this supposed to do: `classRoster.~Roster();`?  Why are you explicitly calling the destructor here?  That type of coding is reserved for `placement-new`, and you are not using placement-new anywhere in your program.  You should remove that line of code.

Comment: Don't pass along just the array, also pass along a `std::size_t` saying how big the array is.  The `sizeof a / sizeof a[0]` technique only works when the array is in scope, rather than a pointer to the `a[0]` (arrays readily decay to pointers to the first element).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I removed the sizeof technique on the array, pulled the arrayNum++ piece out of the classRosterArray push, and just added the increment after that statement. I'm guessing that the increment was allowing for there to be more space in the array than was actually allotted to it. But if that's the case... then why did the function call not show me a similar warning? I'd assume that they are both cases of a potential buffer overflow vulnerability, but that only the constructor use was flagged by the warning system. Thoughts?